# Can these logic circuits be minimised any more?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have four Boolean functions for four outputs, one for each. I've found the equivalent logic circuits for each in what I believe to be the simplest form but that is what I'm asking. Can these circuits be simplified more in any way so to minimise the chip (logic gate) count?

Not sure how to embed pictures but here are the Booleans:
$$a) AD'+AB'C'$$
$$b) ABD'$$
$$c) B'CD'+ACD'$$
$$d)B'C'D$$
I realise I can rewrite a) and c) but do I want to? My aim is to get a circuit with as little logic gates as possible. I was thinking I could use a NOR gate followed by an OR gate for a) to reduce the number of NOT gates I'd need.

Comment: Which gates do you have available? One answer below makes use of three-input AND gates -- is that cheaper for you than two two-input ANDs? If you're counting chips rather than gates, is there a bonus for keeping the number of different _kinds_ of gates low?

Comment: Well, when I say chips I mean gates, specifically e.g. 7402, 7404 etc. I have the seven basic ones at my disposal: AND, NOT, OR, NOR, NAND, XOR and XNOR. I don't need to factor cost into it either. This is purely for simulation. This question will help me with an overarching problem I haven't described here where bonus marks are available for using a lesser amount of gates.

Comment: A 7402 has four NOR gates in one package. If you have a circuit that uses one NOR gate and another that uses two, would that be a reason to prefer one over the other? You'd need one 7402 in either case. And I don't know what you mean by "don't need to factor cost into it". You can't even _start_ talking about optimizing anything without having a cost function that you want to minimize.

Comment: Well, I'm not doing the circuit physically. I'm using a simulation package called Multisim which is just used to simulate what a circuit will behave like. Cost doesn't come into it. This isn't real life, per se. Maybe I need to provide some extra context.

Comment: if you have no concept of cost, there is no reason to prefer one circuit to another. Just use the first one that comes to mind. (Note that a cost function does not need to give a value in money -- but unless you have something to define which solutions you would prefer over others, you have not in fact asked a meaningful question).

Comment: And you're contradicting yourself because in your own question you say you want to "minimize the gate count". That makes the gate count your cost function, and it is not coherent to claim that you don't have one.

Comment: I did define what solutions are preferable over others. I want to see if those four individual logic circuits can be simplified which will help me create an overall circuit where a 2-chip solution is the best answer. Without the question I've been asked, it's difficult to explain but you're not supposed to do that on here. I think you're being deliberately obtuse, Henning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91636/discussion-between-austeretiger-and-henning-makholm).

Answer (score 0):

One equivalent circuit, not much smaller though:

[image]

a)=f, b)=g, c)=h, d)=i

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the layout of your diagram. I also think you've misunderstood my question, sorry. I meant could any of those four individual circuits be simplified to reduce the number of logic gates, not the overall circuit.